# Прямая речь двух человек

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Запуталась в знаках препинания. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно оформить этот текст.

*Нашёл какие-то огрызки росписи на уцелевшем своде потолка — "это двенадцатый век, Майкл!" "Угу", говорил Майкл.*

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Словосочетание **огрызки росписи** мне не нравится (контекста, правда, маловато).
Кто же ее (штукатурку) так погрыз-то — время, драконы или гигантские летучие мыши?
Мне кажется, что можно использовать эти слова: *остатки, ошмётки, пятна, фрагменты, куски.*

Вместо нейтрального глагола **говорил** лучше употребить другой, показывающий эмоции или их отсутствие. Например: *буркнул, пробубнил, промычал, вздохнул, проговорил, пробурчал, пробормотал.*
И ещё: дважды, совсем рядом, повторяются имена — или их надо разъединить, или одно заменить на местоимение.

1. *Нашёл какие-то ошмётки росписи на уцелевшем своде потолка.

   — Майкл, это двенадцатый век!

   — Угу, — пробурчал Майкл.*
2. *Нашёл какие-то остатки росписи на уцелевшем своде потолка.

   — Это двенадцатый век, Майкл!

   — Угу, — пробубнилось в ответ.*

Comment: Ну и в строчечку: *Нашёл какие-то ошмётки росписи на уцелевшем своде потолка. "Майкл, это двенадцатый век!" — "Угу", — пробурчал Майкл.*

Comment: Стилистически там как раз все укладывается в контекст - и огрызки (повествование ведется от лица не очень образованного человека), и повторение имени. Загвоздка только в оформлении речи персонажей. "Майкл, это двенадцатый век!" — "Угу", — пробурчал Майкл. - это единственный верный вариант записать в строчку? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Море вариантов.

Что называется, свободно от бедра:

> Нашёл какие-то огрызки росписи на уцелевшем своде потолка: "Это
>   двенадцатый век, Майкл!"
>
> Угу, говорил Майкл.

А этот построже:

> Нашёл какие-то огрызки росписи на уцелевшем своде потолка.
>
> — Это двенадцатый век, Майкл!
>
> — Угу, — говорил Майкл.